# Validation of password and repassword with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, passwords

This is the final part of a switch statement to validate a register form:

```
    case "contraseña":
    {
        if($(this).val().length < 9){
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("Debe tener más de 8 caracteres");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#C60");
            contraseñaValida = false;
        }else{
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("Correcto");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#990");
            contraseñaValida = true;
        }
    break;
    }
    case "repetirContraseña":
    {
        if($(this).val() === $("#contraseña").val()){
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("Correcto");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#990");
            repContraseñaValida = true;
        }else{
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("Debe coincidir con su contraseña");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#C60");
            repContraseñaValida = false;
        }
    break;
    }
    if($("#checkbox_legales").is(":checked")){
        checkbox_legalesValido = true;
    }else{
        checkbox_legalesValido = false;
    }
    habilitarBoton()
}
}
```

Something is wrong with the `"repetirContraseña" case` because firebug don't allow me to set stopping points in that part and the last if and the `habilitarBoton()` function isn't being called. Can you figure out what is wrong?

Comment: never seen someone using stuff like "ñ" ID ...

Comment: what means sometimes is wrong=? its not getting in this "case" or in this "case" ists something wrong? dont understand sry..

Comment: something not sometime. The case works because if I write the pass I writed in the contraseña case it shows "Correcto", but the last if and the hablitarBoton() are not being read.

Comment: ah something ye sry... maybe the `break;` might be bad there..

Answer (score 0):

some thing like this:

```
case "repetirContraseña":
    {
        if($(this).val() === $("#contraseña").val()){
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("Correcto");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#990");
            repContraseñaValida = true;
        }else{
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("Debe coincidir con su contraseña");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#C60");
            repContraseñaValida = false;
        }
    if($("#checkbox_legales").is(":checked")){
        checkbox_legalesValido = true;
    }else{
        checkbox_legalesValido = false;
    }
    habilitarBoton()
    break;
    }
```

or

```
case "repetirContraseña":
    {
        if($(this).val() === $("#contraseña").val()){
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("Correcto");
           $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#990");
            repContraseñaValida = true;
        }else{
            $(".texto_req_reg").html("Debe coincidir con su contraseña");
            $(".texto_req_reg").css("color", "#C60");
            repContraseñaValida = false;
        }
    }
default : {
  if($("#checkbox_legales").is(":checked")){
        checkbox_legalesValido = true;
    }else{
        checkbox_legalesValido = false;
    }
    habilitarBoton()
}
```